# python: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory - ongoing issue with pandas "to_csv"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, operating-system, pyscripter

I have been banging my head against the wall and neither I or chatgpt can figure out why my file won't save.

```
import pygbif
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_dir = "C:/myfiles/flies_and_moths"
os.chdir(my_dir)

cwd = os.getcwd()
new_folder = "occurrence_files"
extract_to_directory = os.path.join(cwd, new_folder)

for csv_file in os.listdir(extract_to_directory):
    try:
        full_path = os.path.join(extract_to_directory, csv_file)
        # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
        df = pd.read_csv(full_path, sep='\t', low_memory= False)
        taxon_key2 = df['taxonKey'].iloc[0]
        species_name2 = species.name_lookup(taxonKey=taxon_key2)
        # Modify DataFrame using .loc
        df.loc[:, "catalogNumber"] = df["catalogNumber"].astype(str)
        df.loc[:, "CATALOG_NO"] = df["institutionCode"] + '' + df["catalogNumber"]
        conditions = [
            df['establishmentMeans'].isin(['INTRODUCED', 'INVASIVE', 'MANAGED', 'NATURALISED']),
            df['establishmentMeans'] == 'NATIVE',
            df['establishmentMeans'] == 'UNCERTAIN'
        ]
        values = ['3', '1', '5']
        df.loc[:, "ORIGIN"] = np.select(conditions, values, default = "1")
        keeps = ['decimalLatitude', 'decimalLongitude', 'basisOfRecord','year','CATALOG_NO', 'ORIGIN']
        # Select only the specified columns
        df2 = df.loc[:, keeps]
        df2["SPATIAL_REF"] ="WGS84"
        df2["YEAR"] = "2024"
        df2["CITATION"] = "GBIF 2024"
        df2["PRESENCE"] = "1"
        df2["BINOMIAL"] = f"{species_name2}"
        df2["SEASONAL"] = "1"
        df2["COMPILER"] = f"{assessors_name}"
        # Rename columns
        df2.rename(columns={"decimalLatitude": "DEC_LAT","decimalLongitude": "DEC_LONG","basisOfRecord": "BasisOfRec","year": "EVENT_YEAR"}, inplace=True)
        #make csv from dataframe
        outname =f'{species_name2}.csv'
        if not os.path.exists(extract_to_directory):
            os.mkdir(extract_to_directory)
        fullname = os.path.join(extract_to_directory, outname)
        df2.to_csv(fullname)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"did not write new file: {e}")
```

```
ERROR:
did not write new file: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: 'C:\myfiles\flies_and_moths\occurrence_files\{'offset': 0, 'limit': 100, 'end......
```

Then it keeps listing the entire contents of the csv which is thousands of entries

I tried checking that directory exists:

```
C:\myfiles\flies_and_moths\occurrence_files
I checked that the dataframe exists:
>>> print(df2)
       DEC_LAT    DEC_LONG  ... SEASONAL    COMPILER
0    35.104935 -111.004723  ...        1  
1    36.047530 -104.377200  ...        1  
2    32.059819 -110.076233  ...        1  
3    31.978887 -108.823113  ...        1  
4    32.059991 -110.076137  ...        1  
..         ...         ...  ...      ...         ...
136  35.238000 -111.576000  ...        1  
137  32.430600 -107.762000  ...        1  
138  31.883405 -109.204969  ...        1  
139  34.212954 -111.460799  ...        1  
140  34.212954 -111.460799  ...        1  

[141 rows x 13 columns]
```

The file csv names look like this, but that shouldn't matter because it opens these files just fine: 0034528-240229165702484.csv

I googled this and used chatgpt to try and fix this, nothing worked

Comment: There's no need to check if the output directory exists, since it's the same as the input directory. If it didn't exist, `os.listdir(extract_to_directory)` would fail.

Comment: What does `print(outname2)` show?

Comment: It looks like `\{'offset': 0, 'limit': 100, 'end......` has gotten into the filename. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, the outname is what I wasn't expecting because I misunderstood what the species name was pulling - thank you